# CUDA on a system that has no GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I do not have a GPU card installed in my system. I would like to know if there is any way I can code in CUDA and access CUDA libraries on my GPU-less laptop?

Comment: Might I recommend OpenCL since it's not tied to nvidia. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850358/when-writing-opencl-code-how-does-it-perform-on-a-single-core-machine-without-a. Comparison: http://wiki.tiker.net/CudaVsOpenCL

Comment: Related: [GPU Emulator for CUDA programming without the hardware](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36273426/4694621)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a CUDA emulator such as

https://code.google.com/p/cuda-waste/

https://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/

Note that the performance for many tasks will be far inferior to an actual GPU, but you can learn the programming model with an emulator.

Comment: These are both long out of support and unusable in 2019

Comment: Feel free to add an answer that's valid in 2019. This answer was posted in 2013.

Comment: The best solution is to delete this. The question is closed as a duplicate of a modern relevant answer